# How to extract where clause as array in spark sql?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract where clause from SQL query.
Multiple conditions in where clause should be in form array. Please help me.

Sample Input String:

```
select * from table where col1=1 and (col2 between 1 and 10 or col2 between 190 and 200) and col2 is not null
```

Output Expected:

```
Array("col1=1", "(col2 between 1 and 10 or col2 between 190 and 200)", "col2 is not null")
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My question here is like... I would like to split all the conditions as separate items... let's say my query is like

```
select * from table where col1=1 and (col2 between 1 and 10 or col2 between 190 and 200) and col2 is not null
```

The output I'm expecting is like

```
List("col1=1", "col2 between 1 and 10", "col2 between 190 and 200", "col2 is not null")
```

The thing is the query may have multiple levels of conditions like

```
select * from table where col1=1 and (col2 =2 or(col3 between 1 and 10 or col3 is between 190 and 200)) and col4='xyz'
```

in output each condition should be a separate item

```
List("col1=1","col2=2", "col3 between 1 and 10", "col3 between 190 and 200", "col4='xyz'")
```

Comment: Can you parse your `sql` query string?

Comment: Hi @sarvan you don't differentiate `AND` and `OR` is that intended ?

Comment: Hi @Baitmbarek, basically I'm trying to extract all the children from the tree irrespective of AND or OR. I was trying some recursive fn to extract but of no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use Regex for this. Here's an alternative way to extract your conditions based on Catalyst's Logical Plan :

```
val plan = df.queryExecution.logical
val predicates: Seq[Expression] = plan.children.collect{case f: Filter =>
    f.condition.productIterator.flatMap{
      case And(l,r) => Seq(l,r)
      case o:Predicate => Seq(o)
    }
}.toList.flatten

println(predicates)
```

Output :

```
List(('col1 = 1), ((('col2 >= 1) && ('col2 <= 10)) || (('col2 >= 190) && ('col2 <= 200))), isnotnull('col2))
```

Here the predicates are still `Expressions` and hold information (tree representation).

**EDIT** :
As asked in comment, here's a String (user friendly I hope) representation of the predicates :)

```
val plan = df.queryExecution.logical
val predicates: Seq[Expression] = plan.children.collect{case f: Filter =>
    f.condition.productIterator.flatMap{
      case o:Predicate => Seq(o)
    }
}.toList.flatten

def stringifyExpressions(expression: Expression): Seq[String] = {
  expression match{
    case And(l,r) => (l,r) match {
      case (gte: GreaterThanOrEqual,lte: LessThanOrEqual) => Seq(s"""${gte.left.toString} between ${gte.right.toString} and ${lte.right.toString}""")
      case (_,_) => Seq(l,r).flatMap(stringifyExpressions)
    }
    case Or(l,r) => Seq(Seq(l,r).flatMap(stringifyExpressions).mkString("(",") OR (", ")"))
    case eq: EqualTo => Seq(s"${eq.left.toString} = ${eq.right.toString}")
    case inn: IsNotNull => Seq(s"${inn.child.toString} is not null")
    case p: Predicate => Seq(p.toString)
  }
}

val stringRepresentation = predicates.flatMap{stringifyExpressions}

println(stringRepresentation)
```

New Output :

```
List('col1 = 1, ('col2 between 1 and 10) OR ('col2 between 190 and 200), 'col2 is not null)
```

You can keep playing with the recursive `stringifyExpressions` method if you want to customize the output.

**EDIT 2 :** In response to your own edit :

You can change the `Or` / `EqualTo` cases to the following

```
def stringifyExpressions(expression: Expression): Seq[String] = {
  expression match{
    case And(l,r) => (l,r) match {
      case (gte: GreaterThanOrEqual,lte: LessThanOrEqual) => Seq(s"""${gte.left.toString} between ${gte.right.toString} and ${lte.right.toString}""")
      case (_,_) => Seq(l,r).flatMap(stringifyExpressions)
    }
    case Or(l,r) => Seq(l,r).flatMap(stringifyExpressions)
    case EqualTo(l,r) =>
      val prettyLeft = if(l.resolved && l.dataType == StringType) s"'${l.toString}'" else l.toString
      val prettyRight = if(r.resolved && r.dataType == StringType) s"'${r.toString}'" else r.toString
      Seq(s"$prettyLeft=$prettyRight")
    case inn: IsNotNull => Seq(s"${inn.child.toString} is not null")
    case p: Predicate => Seq(p.toString)
  }
}
```

This gives the 4 elements List :

```
List('col1=1, 'col2 between 1 and 10, 'col2 between 190 and 200, 'col2 is not null)
```

For the second example :

```
select * from table where col1=1 and (col2 =2 or (col3 between 1 and 10 or col3 between 190 and 200)) and col4='xyz'
```

You'd get this output (`List[String]` with 5 elements) :

```
List('col1=1, 'col2=2, 'col3 between 1 and 10, 'col3 between 190 and 200, 'col4='xyz')
```

**Additional note**: If you want to print the attribute names without the starting quote, you can handle it by printing this instead of toString :

```
node.asInstanceOf[UnresolvedAttribute].name
```

Comment: i would like to get the output like below 
`List("col1=1","col2 between 1 and 10", "col2 between 190 and 200", "col2 is not null")`
can you please help me on this

Comment: The `between` keyword is a special case of `And(l,r)`. I'll give it a try in the next few days.

Comment: @sarvan Hi ! Just edited the answer with I hope a more human readable output ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. My question is lil different. im updating my qn in the original qn.

Comment: @sarvan you can take a look at the **EDIT 2** it should match your needs. You can change the string representation as required if needed, depending on your usage.